# How to implement multiple login screens for Angular App

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-ui-router, authorization

I have a requirement from my org's InfoSec team to have separate logins for the admin portion of my app from the rest of the users.

How can I implement multiple login screens/urls (i.e. one for admin, the other for customers) for the same app? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a very open ended question, depends up on your existing architecture and can be solved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple login screens is actually not that difficult. A login screen is just a page registered with a route that accepts credentials as input and authorizes a user.

You can just give your admin users the link to the admin login and customer users the link to the customer login.

You can then record which page they used to login and redirect them back there when they logout.